# Java ical4j cannot get categories

Tags: java, android, ical4j

Any ical4j experts out there who can help me? I need to get the categories for an `.ics` file using `getCategories()` but it isn't recognized because the jar files do not have that method yet, but all the code is there to retrieve it I just need to add the getCategories() method to a .class in the jar. I'm using ical4j 1.0.6. Anybody out there who has gotten the categories of an ics file using ical4j ( I know it's capable)? I've already tried to edit the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
Categories cats = (Categories)event.getProperty(Property.CATEGORY)
```

And actually, since, per RFC5545, the CATEGORY property can be multivalued, you should probably call event.getProperties(Property.CATEGORY) which will return a PropertyList

Comment: And this will give me the categories of the VEvent?